# Object array for widgets in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, widget

I'm having a simple GUI environment with a button widget (a jQuery plugin). There's a gui object which holds all widgets like:

```
myGui["button1"] = button1;
myGui["button2"] = button2;
```

What I want to do is defining a widget array like:

```
myGui["button"][0] = button1;
myGui["button"][1] = button2;
```

But I'm getting an error:

> myGui["button"] is undefined

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set up the array first:

```
myGui['button'] = [];
```

then

```
myGui['button'][0] = button1;
```

should work. Or, you could do this:

```
myGui['button'] = [button1, button2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first do:

```
myGui["button"] = [];
```

This creates an array, after that you can use it as one.

On an unrelated note, you can use a bit nicer (in my opinion, anyway) syntax:

```
myGui.button = [];
myGui.button[0] = button1;
myGui.button[1] = button2;
```

Also if you want to simply always append at the end of array, you don't need to specify `[n]` yourself, but can use `.push()`:

```
myGui.button = [];
myGui.button.push(button1);
myGui.button.push(button2);
```

It does the same thing ultimately.